# Magento PHP : Products without parents

Tags: php, magento, product, parents

In Magento, on a script I would like to filter the products who don't have any parent product.
Currently I do something like :

```
$products = $this->_productModel->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id',array('in'=>$_types))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('in'=>$_status))
    ->joinTable('cataloginventory/stock_item', 'product_id=entity_id', array('qty'=>'qty','is_in_stock' => 'is_in_stock'), $this->_getStockSQL(), 'inner');
```

I got all the products, but can I say "give me only the products without parents" using getCollection() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parent product and child product are only avialable in grouped, configurable, and bundle product. If you don't want parent product

Check if id is in parent_id in catalog_product_relation and catlog_product_super_link then its a parent product

Answer (score 0):

Perfect :)

```
->joinTable('catalog_product_relation', "parent_id=entity_id",array('child_id'=>'child_id'), null, "inner")
```

Thanks